# XFS space full and also inode got full too? How could this happen?

Tags: inode, sles, xfs

```
# df . -i
Filesystem                Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vgFOO-lv_bar  53136 52857   279  100% /bar
# df . -h
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vgFOO-lv_bar   50G   50G   20K 100% /bar
# find . | wc -l
52855
# lsof /bar | grep -i deleted
# 
# findmnt /bar
TARGET SOURCE                    FSTYPE OPTIONS
/bar   /dev/mapper/vgFOO-lv_bar xfs    rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota
```

So the space got full and also the inodes too. But this looks false from inode POV, since there were just 52855 files there.. and we removed some bigger files and space was available again.

**The question**: is this normal for XFS? That if the space gets full, the inodes will get to 100% too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Inodes in XFS are dynamically allocated, which means that, unlike many other Linux file systems, their location and number are not determined at mkfs time."

Your 53,000 files ate all the free space, leaving no room for new inodes.